# Build a SaaS using .dwg file (autocad) or extract plan from .dwg

Tags: javascript, autocad, dwg, libredwg

I'm looking to make a SaaS app using .dwg files. The user will import a floor plan of a room and my algo will calculate the best way to install floor heating cable. I never use Autocad and I'm wondering how I can extract the principal geometry of my plan. I'm open to any language even if I prefer javascript.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are some webservices available via [Autodesk Forge](http://developer.autodesk.com). You can use [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2) to process a .dwg file. It's accessible via REST protocols, so you can call from JavaScript/NodeJS, for instance.

To take full advantage of Design Automation API for .DWG, you can write a [.DLL plugin (with .NET)](http://www.autodesk.com/developautocad) that will perform complex tasks on the file, but note that the .dwg file contains basic geometry, so you may need to interpret it.

Check out some [samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=design.automation).

Comment: The cost of the API is too expensive for my project. I've like 100 floor plan/month to analyse and 400$/month is too much...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I would like to hear more about it. Can you reach me by email? It's my first name DOT last name @autodesk.com.

Comment: just sent you an email !

Comment: Note that the free tier includes 1 hour of processing time per month. How do you know that is not enough to process your 100 drawings/month? Let's say a drawing takes 20 seconds then you will burn 100*20s = 34 minutes, well within the free tier.